# Difference in pointer arithmetic (&x[5]-x)

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following snippet:

```
int main(){
    int x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("\n%d\n", &x[2]-x);
}
```

I know that in pointer arithmetic, `&x[5]-&x[2]` gives 3 for example, because subtraction returns the difference in the pointer's type between two pointers. But I can't understand how the machine processes `&x[2]-x` since it outputs 2.

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, `x` being a lvalue to an array of type `int [5]` means that it can implicitly decay to a pointer to the first element when used in such an expression, so in a sense the code is preforming the same function as `&x[2] - &x[0]` would.

You can read more about array to pointer decay [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay). Note that this is also how for example the subscript operator works by its definition of `a[b]` being identical to `*(a + b)`, in this case `a` would decay to a pointer to the first element and via pointer arithmetic with `b` end up pointing at the desired element to be dereferenced.

Comment: Another way to express it, using the equivalence of `a[b]` to `*(a + b)`, is that the OP's expression `&x[2]-x` becomes `&*(x + 2) - x`. The address-of and dereference operators (`&*`) cancel each other out and it becomes `x + 2 - x` or `2`.